# how can i convert text to speech without using Openears library?

Tags: iphone, xcode, object, text-to-speech

i have a string.i need to convert it to Voice.
can any one help me to convert text to speech.
now i am using Openears library for this.however there is some problem when i  convert text to speech.can any one provide me a good way to do it without Openears library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Flite](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/flite/) may be worth investigating. See [this blog post](http://artofsystems.blogspot.com/2009/02/speech-synthesis-on-iphone-with-flite.html).

Answer (score 0):

NSSpeechSynthesizer class is there for Mac application. I think it also supports iPhone. Have dig at it. If you have Arron Hillegass "Cocoa Programming for Mac" book, you can find Mac application. All the best.